# Covering lemmas in Hochman's ''On self-similar sets with overlaps and inverse theorems for entropy''

Tags: co.combinatorics, fractals, dimension-theory, self-similarity

I am confused about the covering lemmas in the captioned work and really hope to get some ideas here.

Firstly it is lemma 3.7. ([Image of Lemma 3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un5Xb.png)) (for convenience here is the lemma of this lemma ([Image of Lemma 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU2jE.png)))

I do not understand the ''$\supseteq$'' in the line 
''$J'\cap(J'-\ell)\supseteq \cdots$''. Also I am wondering if the following provides a counter-example of this line and this lemma:

Let $n=12$, $I=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$, $m=3$. Then $I'=\{0,4,8\}$ by the construction in Lemma 3.6. Let $J=\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12\}$, $\delta=0.5$. Then for all $i\in I$, $|[i,i+3]\cap J|=2\geq(1-\delta)m$. Take $\ell=1$. Then for all $J'\subseteq J$, we have $J'\cap(J'-\ell)\subseteq J\cap(J-\ell)=\emptyset$, $\bigcup_{i\in I'} J\cap[i,i+2]=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$, and $(1-\delta-\frac{\ell}{m})|I|=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})\cdot 9 >0$.

Secondly, it is lemma 3.8.([Excerpt for Lemma 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9qyd.png)), which I am not sure how the marked inequality is obtained.

Since subsequent results depends on these lemmas and this paper is already acknowledged in the field, I think there should be an answer for resolving my confusion.

Thanks for help!